# Database Rollback not working with magento 2.1.9?

Tags: magento-2.1, magento-2.1.9

[image]

I created one test DB backup "test backup", when trying to rollback with SSH it only looks for somecode_db.sql file instead this backup contains the name in it's file. is it magento2.1.9 bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an issue with Magento2., I reported this issue and now it is on their TODO list.

[github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12064](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/12064)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this still happens in Magento 2.2.2 although they've reported it as fixed.
The rollback itself it deletes the SQL file...

After losing one backup, I've done the rollback manually by dropping the database, recreate and then import, `mysql db_name < db_file.sql`.